# How to check if an element is present in the event bubbling propagation tree?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any alternate way of doing this?

```
hammertime.on('pan', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains("disableEvent")) return false
  if(e.target.parentElement?.classList?.contains("disableEvent")) return false
  if(e.target.parentElement?.parentElement?.classList?.contains("disableEvent")) return false
  move()
}
```

I.e., check if the `e.target` is inside the element with the class `disableEvent`.

Comment: Try recursively for last  parent element . Until it becomes null .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foolproof way is to recursively keep checking the parents of the node;

```
function hasParentWithMatchingSelector (target:Node, selector:string) {
    const allSubMenus : NodeListOf<Element> = document.querySelectorAll(selector) 
    let myArray = Array.from(allSubMenus)
    return [...myArray].some(el =>
      el !== target && el.contains(target)
    )
  }
```

Perks including checking other things too.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `.closest()` with a selector that matches the class.

```
hammertime.on('pan', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest(".disableEvent")) {
    move();
  }
});
```